# How to prevent XSS injection in angularjs and webapi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am  implementing OWASP in my project and using (angular js and web api) . Can someone please help me to prevent XSS attack in my project. I have used ngsanitize to prevent script injection while inserting code from UI and it is working fine but using fiddler I am able to inject the script through web api.

Can you please help  me with the best  approach on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`

then you should be able to restrict your controllers/endpoints by decorating them with

`[EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebsite.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

This will restrict that controller/endpoint to only accept CORS requests from that site. Have you tried reading [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) on the asp.net site?

And to stop XSS you could try some sort of data validation. Have you got any of the code you're using to show how this XXS is being done on your webapi?

Comment: I have already implemented CORS in my application but finding it difficult for XSS.

Comment: Ok so can you update your question with an example or some code?

Comment: I have added filter to my actions on                                                                  base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext); an it is encrypting data before sending to the DB